# Creating a menuBar in a frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Label, StringVar, Entry, Button, Menu, Frame, Tk, Canvas
import subprocess
from Tkconstants import LEFT, CENTER,W, SUNKEN , X, Y

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            container = tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            print "Hellooo Stack"
            self.frames = {}
            for F in (MainWindow,Master):
                frame = F(container, self)
                self.frames[F] = frame

                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame(MainWindow)

        def show_frame(self, c):
            '''Show a frame for the given class'''
            frame = self.frames[c]
            frame.tkraise()
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            button = tk.Button(self, text="Connections",compound=LEFT)
            button.pack(pady=50)
            button1 = tk.Button(self, text="   Locker            ", compound=LEFT,
                                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Master))
            button1.pack(pady=50)

class Master(tk.Frame): 
       def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            menubar = Menu(self)
            filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
            filemenu.add_command(label="New",)
            filemenu.add_command(label="Open",)
            filemenu.add_command(label="Save As..")
            filemenu.add_command(label="Colour")
            filemenu.add_command(label="Close")
            menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=filemenu)
            controller.configure(menu = menubar)
if __name__ == "__main__":

        app = SampleApp()
        app.title("APPS")

        app.mainloop()
```

the above code which i posted works fine but the menu displays in all the windows but i wanted the menu to displayed in only one window....i used controller.configure so the menu is displayed in all windows but if i use self.configure i am getting an error...can some one please help me

Comment: When you say "in a frame", do you literally mean in a frame? Or, are you trying to add standard menubar to the main window?

Comment: i meant only in that frame Master not in all the frames...if i place controller.configure(menu=menubar) in the place of self.configure i am getting the menu in all the frames...but i just wanted in one frame

Comment: @BryanOakley could you please help me i am stuck here because i could add the menu

Comment: if you need more help about menubar here you'll find it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menu.htm

Answer (score 2):

You cannot attach a menu to a frame. The only widget with a menu option is the root window and Toplevel windows.

If you want to put a menu inside a frame, you will need to create a frame, add one or more [Menubutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menubutton.htm) widgets, and attach a menu to each of those.

Comment: i am new to tk so could you please add that part in my code

Comment: could you please run my code and see i am getting the menu bar both in mainwindow and master frame...i just wanted the menubar in the master frame

Comment: @user9213: I don't need to run your code. Like I said, you can't attach menus to frames, only to toplevel windows. If you want the menu to appear only sometime, you can always remove it from the main window when one frame is visible, and add it when the other frame is visible.

Comment: please can u show me an example where the menu is visible in one frame and not visible in another frame...i would be great help..!